# Accessing multiple elements by getElementsByClassName() with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to create multiple popups on one page that would appear after clicking a button corresponding to them. I currently have them under the same class, as in here:

```
<div>
    <!-- Popup -->
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup-content">
                Some text here
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <img src="button.png" class="popup-button"/>
</div>
```

The problem is that I am struggling to access individual elements with my javascript code. I am not sure what to replace the manual array accessing ( [0] right now ) with.

```
<script>
// Get the popup
var popup = document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0];

// Get the button that opens the popup
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-button")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the popup (hidden by default)
btn.onclick = function() {
    popup.style.display = "block";
}

</script>
```

Now, I could create multiple scripts and access the arrays manually for each element but of course I am trying to automate it, so that script would run depending on which button was clicked. Say, if 5th button was clicked, 5th popup appears. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to link multiple elements in Javascript is using an id through [the dataset of the elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```js
// Get the popup's btn list
var popupsBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-btn");

// Go through the popup's btn list
for (var i = 0; i < popupsBtn.length; i++) {
  
  // Define the onclick event on popup's btn
  popupsBtn[i].onclick = function() {
  
    // Get the popup associated to the btn with the data-popup-id
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup-" + this.dataset.popupId);
    
    // Use a class to toggle popup visible or not
    popup.classList.toggle("visible");
    
  }
  
}
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="popup-1" class="popup">popup 1 here</div>
      <img src="button.png" class="popup-btn" data-popup-id="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="popup-2" class="popup">popup 2 here</div>
      <img src="button.png" class="popup-btn" data-popup-id="2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="popup-3" class="popup">popup 3 here</div>
      <img src="button.png" class="popup-btn" data-popup-id="3" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your HTML, it would probably be easiest to just access the previous sibling of the clicked button to get to the `.popup`, and then change its style:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.popup-button').forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = () => {
    button.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  };
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      Some text here1
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />
</div>
<div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      Some text here2
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />
</div>
<div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      Some text here3
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />
</div>
```

Comment: It is a cool solution but unfortunately there were some elements in between that I emitted for simplicity. Do you have another idea maybe?

Comment: Post your *actual* code, not the "simplified" code, that way answerers have a [MCVE] to work with

Answer (score 0):

You can use other attributes to identify the button. You could not rely on the className alone. 
You can use `data-id` attribute and pass it in the method. using `this.`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML structure, there are multiple possibilities.

Anyway, I suggest you to use `.querySelectorAll()` to get your elements, and then use a `.forEach()` to execute your code.

I tried to use much of your code to make it work correctly.

**With a parent div**

```js
// Get all the buttons that opens the popups
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-button");

btns.forEach(function(btn, index) {
  // When the user clicks the button, open the popup that is in the same parent div
  btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.closest('div').querySelector('.popup').style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 1</div>
  </div>
  <img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />1
</div>

<div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 2</div>
  </div>
  <img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />2
</div>

<div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 3</div>
  </div>
  <img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />3
</div>
```

---

**Without a parent div**

```js
// Get the popups
var popups = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
// Get the buttons that opens the popups
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-button");

btns.forEach(function(btn, index) {
  // When the user clicks the button, open the popup (hidden by default)
  btn.onclick = function() {
    popups[index].style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 1</div>
</div>
<img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 2</div>
</div>
<img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 3</div>
</div>
<img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />
```

This solution withour parent `div` will work even if the popups and the buttons are not next to each other. But the order (and index) of the elements need to be the same. See it here:

```js
// Get the popups
var popups = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
// Get the buttons that opens the popups
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-button");

btns.forEach(function(btn, index) {
  // When the user clicks the button, open the popup (hidden by default)
  btn.onclick = function() {
    popups[index].style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />1
<img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />2
<img src="button.png" class="popup-button" />3

<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 1</div>
</div>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 2</div>
</div>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Pop-up 3</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.